# Sqlite3 search with PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I can't get SQLite `LIKE` search to work with PDO. This works fine with
MySQL and MariaDB but I can't get this to work with SQLite3.
I have also tried with different examples from internet.

I'm using sqlite3 version 3.35.3 and version PHP 8.0.3 on Linux 5.9.

```
echo '<pre>';

$createTable = <<<EOT
    CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL  
    );

    INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES 
    ('alpha'),
    ('beta'),
    ('gamma'),
    ('theta');
EOT;


if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/test.db'))
{    
    echo "#CREATING DB# <br>";    
    $pdo = new \PDO('sqlite:' . __DIR__ . '/test.db');
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $pdo->exec($createTable);
    
    $term = 'et';        
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :term ";    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $prepare = [
        'term' => "'%". $term ."%'"  
    ];        
    echo getPdoCompiledSqlString($sql, $prepare) . '<br>';
    
    if($stmt)
    {
        $stmt->execute($prepare);
        //$stmt->debugDumpParams();
        debugPdo($stmt);
        echo "#FETCHALL# <br>";
        print_r( $stmt->fetchAll() );            
    }
}
else
{
    echo "#DELETING DB#";
    unlink(__DIR__ . '/test.db');
}


function getPdoCompiledSqlString($sql, $params){
    echo "#SQL STRING# <br>";
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($params as $key => $value){ if (is_string($key)) {$keys[] = '/:'.$key.'/';} else {$keys[] = '/[?]/';}}
    return preg_replace($keys, $params, $sql, 1, $count);
}

function debugPdo(&$stmt){    
    echo "#DEBUG PDO OBJ# <br>";
    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
}



echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: In `$pdo->exec($createTable);` you have 2 statements. Perhaps you can only run one statement at a time? Try to `exec()` them separately.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `exec()` is able to exec multiple statements.

Comment: @Syscall OK. Yes, the quote thing is the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to quote the parameter :

```
'term' => "%". $term ."%"
```

Instead of

```
'term' => "'%". $term ."%'"
```

Because the parameter will automatically be quoted during `execute()`

```
$term = 'et';
$sql = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :term ";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$prepare = [
    'term' => "%". $term ."%" //only the search string: `%et%`
];
$stmt->execute($prepare);
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [name] => beta
            [1] => beta
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [name] => theta
            [1] => theta
        )
)
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you.